# WPF TextChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, textchanged

I have a TextBox and a Button inside my WPF application. When the user clicks on the button it saves the textbox's text value into a txt file.
So, basically when the user inserts something in the TextBox, the TextChaned event is triggered. The problem is, for example, if the user types "Daniel" and clicks on the button, every single combination of user's input is also saved. How can I get rid of this?

The text file contains:

```
D
Da
Dan
Dani
Danie
Daniel
```

How can I save only the last string (Daniel) or is there any other event handler for my problem?
Btw, this is actually a list, and I'm using the Add method.

Code, as requested:

```
    // Button, just ignore all the crap inside
    private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/dir.txt") + "/commandline.txt", checkedValues);
    }
    // List 
    private List<String> checkedValues = new List<String>();
    // TextChanged
    private void sWidth_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        checkedValues.Add(sWidth.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use `TextChanged` event? If you only need to save Textbox.Text use `Button_Click` event.

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka what if the TextBox default Text attribute isn't empty? I want to save it too.

Comment: Could you post your code for textchanged and button click?

Comment: You could save the default textbox content value automatically on the `Window_Loaded` event.

Comment: So what if the default TextBox Text is not empty, when the Button Click event is fired it will save whatever Text you have in that TextBox?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka my code works, the only problem is that is saves all the garbage the user types. And I know why. I was asking if there's any other event haldler, similar to TextChanged that will only save the last text input.

Comment: If you use `Button_Click` event to save it will save whatever is in textbox, even if it is empty. If you dont want to save "empty" textbox text just use `if(...){ }`

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: The other event you may look into is `Textbox_Leave`. It will trigger when cursor will leave textbox, like after editing you will click on any other control.

Comment: I second `Textbox_Leave`, but that won't really solve your 'saving of default content' problem.

Comment: Oh, you have something as default but you want to avoid saving it, and only save when user changed anything? I would use `if(Textbox.Text == "your defoult textbox text") { return;} else { ...do your stuff..}` or used `TextChanged` event just to check if anyone made any change here, for exemple by changing some variable, and later chack what state tyhis variable has in `TextChanged` event... Not sure if I am clear

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka, Almost, my TextBox has a default value of "800" (the screen width), when I click on the button, it saves correctly. If I try to change this to "600" for example, it will save "6, 60, 600" - all what I typed.

Comment: THat happens because `TextChanged` is triggered everytime you press button. Everytime you press your button a value of your textbox is stored in the list and that leads to your result. That is why I do not understand why you use his event. If you only whant to check if eneything changed in the textbox use some if statement to do that. Move `checkedValues.Add(sWidth.Text)` to your `Click` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like that:

```
// List 
private List<String> checkedValues = new List<String>();

public int nTextboxChanged = 0;

// Button, just ignore all the crap inside
private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(nTextboxChanged == 1)
    {     
        checkedValues.Add(sWidth.Text);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/dir.txt") + "/commandline.txt", checkedValues);
    }
}

// TextChanged
private void sWidth_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    nTextboxChanged = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want this to be handled by your Button's `Click` event and not the TextBox's `TextChanged` event.

Like this:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("yourtextfile.txt", true))
       {
             streamWriter.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the TextChanged event at all.

xaml

```
<TextBox Name="textToSave" />
<Button Click="saveToTextFile" />
```

cs

```
private void saveToTextFile(...){
   string text = textToSave.Text;

   //code to save to text file

}
```